# Unble to pass Id from VF page to Lightning Component

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, lightning-apps

I have created Custom Button on Case Object using VF Page which contains Lightning Component Inside it. Now I am not able to Pass Current Case ID to the Lightning component which is blocking my development. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance for your support!! :)

### VF Page Code

```
<script>
    $Lightning.use("c:CPM_ContainerApp", function() {
      $Lightning.createComponent("c:CPM_CreateAction",{ 
      },
      "lightning",
      function(cmp) { 
          //cmp.set("v.recordId",ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id'));
      }); 
    });
</script>
```

### Lightning App

### Lightning Component

```
<aura:attribute name="recordTypeId" type="String" access="public"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" access="public"/>
<aura:attribute name="helperExecuted" type="boolean" default="false"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" access="public"/>

<div class="slds">        
</div>
```

### Lightning Component Helper

```
RecTypeId : function(cmp, event, helper) { 
        var action = cmp.get("c.getRecTypeId");
        action.setParams({ 
            CaseId : cmp.get("v.recordId") 
        });     
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS"){
                cmp.set("v.recordTypeId", response.getReturnValue());
                var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
                createRecordEvent.setParams({
                    "entityApiName": "CPM_Action__c",
                    "recordTypeId":cmp.get("v.recordTypeId"),
                    "defaultFieldValues": {
                            'CPMCase__c' : cmp.get("v.recordId"),
                            'CPM_Business_Unit__c':'AWP-APAC',
                            'CPM_Status__c':'New',
                            'CPM_Priority__c' :'Medium',
                    }                    
                });
            createRecordEvent.fire(); 
                cmp.set("v.helperExecuted", true);
            }else if (state === "INCOMPLETE"){
            }else if (state === "ERROR"){
                var errors = response.getError();
                if(errors){
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " + 
                                 errors[0].message);
                    }
                }else{
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the `recordId` from your VF page currently.

The empty braces `{}` in your following snippet represents which [attributes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out_markup.htm) you need to pass to your component and that currently you are not passing anything.

```
$Lightning.createComponent("c:CPM_CreateAction",{}, ....
```

You will need to change it to something as below for the component to receive arguments from the VF page:

```
$Lightning.createComponent("c:CPM_CreateAction",
    {recordId: ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id'), <any other params>}, ....
```